# Python - Continue program after program crash

Tags: python, crash

I have an application which crashes when I give it a certain input. On the command-line prompt, I can see the "Access Violation" message etc.
And the program does not terminate when it processes the input (a sort of not-ending loop). To kill it, I need to type Ctrl+C.

> My question is: How can I skip that crash programmatically ?
>
> I mean: My goal is to give that input to that program, if it crashes I
>   want to store the input and if it does not crash, then I will remove
>   the input and continue with the next input?

My Code is:

```
import subprocess


program_to_call = "C:\\Program Files\\Software\\application.exe"
arg = "-s"

file = "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Project\\templates\\file1"

subprocess.Popen([program_to_call, arg, file], shell=True)   # <---after this line, it does not go to next line 

... code for removing etc.
```

Since I am learning Python, I would like to see some advices, concepts or hints to useful python libraries for my problem in your answers. You do not need to write code snippets.

Note: I am using Windows 7(x86) and python version installed is 2.7.1.

Comment: you could try `subprocess.call([program_to_call, arg, file])` instead, since Popen needs to wait for termination.

Comment: yes but I want also to capture the error message to decide whether it crashes or not. Therefore, I used **code = subprocess.check_output(...)** but it hangs.

Comment: The error message may be written to stdout. Try if calling `subprocess.check_output` with the argument `stderr=sys.stdout` works.

Comment: @L3viathan: yes, I can see the error code on the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to figure out whether the program writes the error message to STDERR or STDOUT. Then you must hope that it flushes its buffer after printing the error message. Finally, you can do this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([program_to_call, ...], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  # or stderr=...
while True:
    out, err = p.communicate()
    # now check whether error message is in out (or err)
    if p.returncode is not None: # process is dead
        break
```

If you give the argument `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` (similar with `stderr`), it will make it so you can check the output of the text on demand. This can either be done by reading from the file object `p.stdout`, or using `p.communicate()`, which has the nice side effect that it fills `p.returncode` if the process is no more.

If this solution doesn't work, the program you call probably doesn't flush the buffer of its output stream, and there's little you can do about that.

Comment: yes, thx it worked. I also solved the problem using a simple try/except block within an endless while-loop. But with your solution, I would store the return code e.g. **code = p.returncode** before the **break** keyword which is also very nice.